# Infinite Loop error thrown when using property accessors in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, infinite-loop

I have a second window which opens when a certain staffname is searched for, this window prompts you to choose between the 2 staff members with the same name. The window then needs to return a value to the parent window to populate a datatemplate with relating data from the xml file.

I've tried to create a string which will be updated with a value depending on which button is clicked, this string can then be returned to the calling method on the first window and populate binding data in the Linq to Xml query.

But when it runs it causes a stackoverflow exception and that it could be an infinite loop. I'm not sure enough about c# to know what to change.

```
public partial class Choice : Window
{
    private string StaffChoice;

    public Choice()
    {                      
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string staffChoice
    {
        get { return this.StaffChoice; }
        set { staffChoice = StaffChoice; }
    }

    private void btnMRG_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StaffChoice = "MRG";
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnRPG_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StaffChoice = "RPG";
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your naming conventions are wrong - the *field* should be called `staffChoice` and the *property* should be called `StaffChoice`. Please read the [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) for more information. However, now look at your property closely:

```
public string staffChoice
{
    get { return this.StaffChoice; }
    set { staffChoice = StaffChoice; }
}
```

What do you think the setter does? There are two problems with it:

- It ignores the value that you're trying to set it to.
- It calls itself recursively.

You *could* fix this by keeping the manually-declared field, fixing the naming conventions, and changing the property to set the variable to `value` like this:

```
private string staffChoice;

public string StaffChoice
{
    get { return staffChoice; }
    set { staffChoice = value; }
}
```

However, it would be simpler to use an automatically implemented property:

```
public string StaffChoice { get; set; }
```

This will create the backing field and the getter/setter for you automatically.

Comment: I think the getter is fine. I think the setter is wrong. He using a non standard naming convention

Comment: @32bitkid: Yes, I've only just noticed that bit. Ick!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice on the naming conventions! I'm really new to coding and teaching myself, so very often getting stuff wrong!

Comment: Thanks those adjustments worked and solved the recursive loop. I should have seen why that wasn't working.

Comment: Although now how would I get the code to break out from this childwindow and return to the point of call in the code of the MainWindow where i can use this StaffChoice string?

Comment: @markhlong: It's not clear what you mean, to be honest - but it sounds like that should be a separate question. (Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for hints about asking clear questions.)

Comment: Thanks again Jon, I will look into it further and post it as a seperate question if needed.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to declare a property like this...

```
public string StaffChoice { get; set; }
```

your problem is you are basically calling the property setter from within the same setter - thus you have a recursive loop. You could change your code like this to make it work...

```
private string StaffChoice;

public string staffChoice
{
    get { return this.StaffChoice; }
    set { StaffChoice = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your setter isn't right, you are assigning a value to itself (causing the infinite loop) and not using `value`.

You should change your code to this, your naming convention looked backwards so I corrected it, hope you don't mind:

```
private string staffChoice;

public Choice()
{                      
    InitializeComponent();
}

public string StaffChoice
{
    get { return staffChoice; }
    set { staffChoice = value; }
}

private void btnMRG_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    staffChoice = "MRG";
    this.Close();
}

private void btnRPG_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    staffChoice = "RPG";
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hey not a problem with the correction, still very new to development in general so just learning as i go!

Answer (score 2):

Your property should be:

```
public string staffChoice
{
    get { return this.StaffChoice; }
    set { this.StaffChoice = value; }
}
```

In your code you are calling the setter again in the setter - hence the infinite recursion.

However, as you are not doing anything special in the setter (like notifying the UI that the property has changed you could simply have:

```
public string staffChoice { get; set; }
```

This "auto property" is a little cleaner.

(BTW: the normal practice is to have the back variable starting with a lower case letter and the public property starting with an upper case one. However, if you are consistent in your application it doesn't really matter.)